# How can I minimize firestore reads in the "setUsername" scenario?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

the code I have now created is working, but I think it is somehow suboptimal, as it does to many database reads
As far as I understand it, the "onAuthStateChange" can be understood like an useEffect hook, which gets called whenever the user authentication state changes (login, logout). Whenever this happens, the database should be checked for the username which has been chosen by the user. But if I take a look at the console the docSnap is logged a fair amount of times which to me indicates that the function gets called more often than just when the user logs in / logs out.

[image]

Context Component

```
import { createContext } from "react/cjs/react.production.min";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth,db } from "./firebase";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const authContext = createContext({
  user: "null",
  username: "null",
});

export default function AuthenticationContext(props) {
  const [googleUser, setGoogleUser] = useState(null);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setGoogleUser(user.displayName);
      setUserID(user.uid);
      getUsername();
    } else {
      setGoogleUser(null);
    }
  });


    const getUsername = async () => {
      const docRef = doc(db, `users/${userID}`);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      if(docSnap.exists()){
        setUsername(docSnap.data().username);
      }
      else{
        setUsername(null);
      }
    };
  

  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={{ user: googleUser, username: username }}>
      {props.children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

What is more, is that when I login with google and submit a username, the components do not get reevaluated - so a refresh is necessary in order for all the changes to take effect, this has something to do with me not updating state in the submitHandler of the login page. If you have some ideas on how I can do this more professionally please let me hear them. Thank you in advance!

Submit Handler on Login Page

```
const submitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(auth.lastNotifiedUid);
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", auth.lastNotifiedUid), {
      displayName: user,
      username: username,
    });
    await setDoc(doc(db, "usernames", username), { uid: auth.lastNotifiedUid });
  };
```

Comment: Can you confirm you are not adding `onAuthStateChanged` listener multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Dharmaraj, you set multiple subscriptions to the authentication state. This is because you call `onAuthStateChanged` in the body of your component, so it is executed on every render.

To avoid this, you should wrap the function in [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) so that you only subscribe on component mounting, and unsubscribe on unmounting:

```
export default function AuthenticationContext(props) {
  /* ... */
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => { /* ... */ });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, the explanation and the example snippet really helped me a lot, now there are only 2 db reads at any time which I think are when mounting and unmounting.
Thank you!